# Laravel Auth::attempt( ) failing

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-4

I am working on a login system using `Laravel 4`. I can successfully `register` users but when I try to `login` using the details - email and password it fails every time and I don't know why.

This is my `Schema` for the `users` table in the `db`:

```
Schema::create('users', function($table){ 
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('fname', 255); 
            $table->string('lname', 255); 
            $table->string('email')->unique(); 
            $table->string('password',128); 
            $table->string('remember_token', 100);
            $table->timestamps(); 
        });
```

This is my `Login Form`:

```
<form action="{{action('HomeController@handleLogin')}}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>
```

This is my `Login Action` in the `HomeController`:

```
public function handleLogin() {

        $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required', 
            'password' => 'required'
        );

        $credentials = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $rules);
        if($validator->passes()){
            echo "Validation passed";
            if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
                echo "Logged In";die();
            }else{
                echo "Logged Failed";die();
            }
        }else{
            echo "Validation failed";die();
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why it is failing, even if I hard code the email and password into the `$credentials` array it will not login.

Any help is much appreciated it.

Register code

```
public function handleRegister(){

        //Validation Rules
        $rules = array(
            'fname'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
            'lname'=>'required|alpha|min:2',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'
        );

        //Validator
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if($validator->passes()){//PASS
            //Save user to DB
            $user = new User;
            $user->fname = Input::get('fname');
            $user->lname = Input::get('lname');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::action('HomeController@getLogin')->with('message', 'Thanks for registering!');
        }else{//FAIL
            //Display Errors
            return Redirect::action('HomeController@getRegister')->with('message', 'The following errors occured')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

    }
```

`Database row`

```
id  type    fname   lname   email   password    school  address_1   address_2   address_3   address_4   remember_token  created_at  updated_at
7   \N  Jack    Coldrick    jackcoldrick@yahoo.com  $2y$10$nRdbkOeEyOB4NLiphGEb5u2Qvcs2Xwu/x7zIcxq3mY3TQWCkiE6a6    \N  \N  \N  \N  \N      2014-08-18 14:01:22 2014-08-18 14:01:22
```

Comment: Did you debug why it doesn't login? I don't know much about Laravel, but doesn't it return an error message?

Comment: Is the password hashed using laravel in the database already, or just a plaintext representation? You may need to properly seed your table with data first.

Comment: I've set my `debug` to `true` in the `app.php` file so it should return any errors that might occur. However in this instance I am getting no errors and it would appear that it is not validating the details correctly against the ones in my `DB`

Comment: @drmarvelous the password is hashed: i've added the `register action` to my question.

Comment: Try using Auth::validate() instead (it'll return a Bool).  Is it validating (this will not attempt to set the cookie)

Comment: Unfortunately still not validating

Comment: Can you you post the corresponding row from your database? Feel free to alter the data in the row, just want to make sure it's all there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59515/discussion-between-drmarvelous-and-javacadabra).

Comment: Have you used `UserTrait` in your model or implemented `UserInterface`?

Comment: Have you setup in the auth.php the right model and table ? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/config/auth.php

Comment: Maybe just go in the Auth::attempt method directly and debug there directly. Brings you quicker to your solution. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d834d51580fd77db5fcea75a2313ce7b1b2e3438/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php

Answer (score 1):

Try to login manually

```
public function handleLogin() {

        $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required', 
            'password' => 'required'
        );

        $credentials = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $rules);
        if($validator->passes()){
            echo "Validation passed";
            $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])
            ->andWhere('password', Hash::make($credentials['email']))
            ->first();

            if(null !== $user && Auth::login($user)){
                echo "Logged In";die();
            }else{
                echo "Logged Failed";die();
            }
        }else{
            echo "Validation failed";die();
        }
    }
```